# W/BroadcastQueue: Appop Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android

I'd like to ask for your help.
I met tricky error as below, that only occurs on a certain device "LG marshmallow phone".

**< Logcat message >** 
09-11 16:42:55.725 1654-4655/? W/BroadcastQueue: Appop Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x8000010 (has extras) } from null (pid=1654, uid=1000) requires appop null due to registered receiver abc.example.com.countrylist/.BootUpReceiver.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <receiver  android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission ="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Your kind tip is very helpful for me. 
Thank you for your review and feedback.

Comment: can you resolve it? i face the similar problem in Samsung old device with android 4.4

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

> android:permission ="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"

I had this problem with exactly this message on `Android 6.0` and a little bit different message on `7.0`, but not on the previous versions. Removing this line did the trick and the app is starting at boot again.